# SQL Server FOR XML row combine rows

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I was originally trying to do this in C# and have ditched that path for a query. I have a table (SiteTest) with a column called "SiteID" and another column in there is called "Services"
[image: Site ID Table]

I then create some temp tables and use cross apply on the "Services" column to get:
[image: Site ID Table Cross Apply]

I am now trying to use the FOR XML:

```
SELECT
   ProviderName
   ,SiteID
   ,SiteName
   ,(
       SELECT
         Services AS [CoveredServiceCode]
       FROM
         ProviderSiteTestTable AS [CoveredService]
         FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT('CoveredServices')
   )
FROM
    ProviderSiteTestTable AS [ProviderSite]
    FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT('ProviderSites')
```

Then I get:

```
<ProviderSites>
    <ProviderSite>
        <ProviderName>Health Center USA</ProviderName>
        <SiteID>15</SiteID>
        <SiteName>Texas Behavioral Health LLC</SiteName>
        <CoveredServices>
          <CoveredService>04</CoveredService>
        </CoveredServices>
    </ProviderSite>
    <ProviderSite>
        <ProviderName>Health Center USA</ProviderName>
        <SiteID>15</SiteID>
        <SiteName>Texas Behavioral Health LLC</SiteName>
        <CoveredServices>
          <CoveredService>08</CoveredService>
        </CoveredServices>
    </ProviderSite>
    ....
    ....
</ProviderSites>
```

Result I am trying to get (all "CoveredServices" for that site under that site):

```
<ProviderSites>
    <ProviderSite>
        <ProviderName>Health Center USA</ProviderName>
        <SiteID>15</SiteID>
        <SiteName>Texas Behavioral Health LLC</SiteName>
        <CoveredServices>
          <CoveredService>04</CoveredService>
          <CoveredService>08</CoveredService>
          ....
        </CoveredServices>
    </ProviderSite>
    ....
    ....
</ProviderSites>
```

**UPDATE**
Looks like doing a group by might be what I am looking for,
testing this now

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT, ProviderID VARCHAR(100),ProviderName VARCHAR(100),SiteID INT,SiteName VARCHAR(100),OpenDate DATE,[Services] VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 (1,'12-000000','Health Center USA',15,'Texas blah','20120107','04')
,(1,'12-000000','Health Center USA',15,'Texas blah','20120107','08')
,(2,'12-000000','Health Center USA',15,'Texas blah','20120107','ab')
,(2,'12-000000','Health Center USA',15,'Texas blah','20120107','cd');

SELECT tbl.ProviderName
      ,tbl.ID
      ,tbl.SiteName
      ,(
        SELECT tbl2.[services] AS CoveredService
        FROM @mockup tbl2
        WHERE tbl2.ID=tbl.ID --correlated sub-query
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
      ) AS CoveredServices
FROM @mockup tbl
GROUP BY tbl.ProviderName,tbl.ID,tbl.SiteName --Control the final Site-Order here...
FOR XML PATH('ProviderSite'),ROOT('ProviderSites');
```

The result

```
<ProviderSites>
  <ProviderSite>
    <ProviderName>Health Center USA</ProviderName>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <SiteName>Texas blah</SiteName>
    <CoveredServices>
      <CoveredService>04</CoveredService>
      <CoveredService>08</CoveredService>
    </CoveredServices>
  </ProviderSite>
  <ProviderSite>
    <ProviderName>Health Center USA</ProviderName>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <SiteName>Texas blah</SiteName>
    <CoveredServices>
      <CoveredService>ab</CoveredService>
      <CoveredService>cd</CoveredService>
    </CoveredServices>
  </ProviderSite>
</ProviderSites>
```

### Some explanation

In most cases `FOR XML PATH` is the best choice. With `AUTO` mode you are allowing the engine to decide the best output. I prefer approaches, where the developer can control everything *by hand*.

I use a `GROUP BY` on the outer `SELECT`. This will reduce the set to *1-row-per-ID*. Then I use a correlated sub-query to create the internal XML *per ID*.

### Some comments

It is a bad idea, to store more than one value per column. If you can change this, try to use a `m:n` model:

- table Provider
- table Services
- mapping table ProviderServices with foreign keys to both sides.

It looks as if the date `OpenDate` and the `ClosedDate` were string columns. This is very dangerous, especially with a culture dependant format (`7/1/2012`) will be the 7th of January or the first of July, depending on your system's culture settings... My code assumes the 7th of January...

For your next question: Please do not post pictures, we do not want to type this in. See my example how I created a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A *stand-alone* (*ready to execute*) sample with just as much data as you need to explain the principles.

### UPDATE

In your case you might include the *string splitting* into the query directly. Try this

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT, ProviderID VARCHAR(100),ProviderName VARCHAR(100),SiteID INT,SiteName VARCHAR(100),OpenDate DATE,[Services] VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
    (1,'12-000000','Health Center USA',15,'Texas blah','20120107','04,08,01,02')
,(2,'12-000000','Health Center USA',15,'Texas blah','20120107','04,08,02,12')

SELECT tbl.ProviderName
        ,tbl.ID
        ,tbl.SiteName
        ,CAST('<CoveredService>' + REPLACE([services],',','</CoveredService><CoveredService>') + '</CoveredService>' AS XML) AS CoveredServices
FROM @mockup tbl
FOR XML PATH('ProviderSite'),ROOT('ProviderSites');
```